# Pydev Eclipse auto suggestion do not showing string.split() method

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

i am learning python. Following some tutorials for doing so. I am using Pydev in eclipse and python 3.6.

Now the issue is, i am not getting auto suggestion for string.split() method and due to that i need to manually write that method call. However eclipse auto suggestion showing other form of split method but not above one. please anyone tell me why is it so???

code

```
filenm = "abc xy z"
list1 = filenm.split(" ")
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange, it seems to be offering `split()` for me properly in Eclipse/PyDev. Can you post a screenshot with the completion you're having there to help diagnosing the issue?